# Probability that n mutations occur in the first half of a protein string

Tags: probability

This is a homework question and I'm just looking for confirmation that I'm solving this correctly, or a nudge in the right direction if I'm not.

> The article “Statistical Method on Nonrandom Clustering with Application to Somatic Mutations in Cancer” [BMC Bioinformatics, 2011, 11(1)] developed a statistical method to discover mutations that lead to cancer by identifying nonrandom clusters of amino acid mutations in protein sequences in cells. In this method, N denotes the length of a protein sequence, and n denotes the total number of mutations in the protein. The position of a mutation is modeled with a discrete uniform distribution between 1 and N.

Suppose that you are a biomedical engineer working on a protein sequence with two mutations and length N = 1000. Assume that the locations of the mutations are independent, and can be the same for two mutations.

A)  Determine the probability that the first mutation occurs in the first half of the protein sequence.

B)  Determine the probability that both of the mutations occur in the first half of the protein sequence.

C)  Determine the probability that at least one of the mutations occurs in the first half of the protein sequence.

My attempt at this is as follows. I'm not sure if this is the right approach...
**A)  Answer = 0.5  ?**

The sequence is 1000 units long, so there are 500 numbers in the first half of the sequence and 500 in the second half. Since it’s a discrete uniform distribution, each number has an equal probability, so $P(X=x)=1/1000$.
$P(X\leq 500)=\sum_{x=1}^{500}1/1000=500/1000=1/2=0.5$

Alternatively, consider *A=the mutation occurs in the first half* and *B=the mutation occurs in the second half.* Then,
$P(A)+P(B)=1$  and  $P(A)=P(B)$
$1=P(A)+P(A)$
$2P(A)=1$
$P(A)=1/2$

**B)  Answer = 0.25 ?**
$P(E_1=A and E_2=A)=\binom{2}{2}(0.5)^2 (0.5)^0=(0.5)^2=0.25$

**C)  Answer = 0.75 ?**
The opposite of at least one mutation occurring in the first half is NO mutations occurring in the first half, which is the same as saying both mutations occur in the second half.
$P(E_1=B and E_2=B)=\binom{2}{2}(0.5)^2 (0.5)^0=(0.5)^2=0.25$
The complement of this is $1-0.25=0.75$

Comment: Also C) $\tbinom 22(0.5)^2(0.5)^0+\tbinom 21(0.5)^1(0.5)^1=0.75$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

The probability for a mutation being placed among the first 500 when selecting from 1000 places without bias is: $1/2$.

The probability for two mutations doing this *independently* is $1/2^2$.

The probability for at least one among two doing this *independently* is $1-1/2^2$.